# Como checar um CRC

Tags: c, linux

Recebo 9 bytes pela serial onde os dois últimos são o CRC-16, preciso verifcar esse CRC pra saber se recebi o bloco corretamente.

```
buffer[0] = 0x2E;
buffer[1] = 0x83;
buffer[2] = 0x82;
buffer[3] = 0x00;
buffer[4] = 0x00;
buffer[5] = 0x00;
buffer[6] = 0x00;
buffer[7] = 0xA9; //CRC-16, LSB
buffer[8] = 0xEF; //CRC-16, MSB
```

Estou tentando fazer uma função para verificar e retornar 0 ou 1 mas estou tendo dificuldades em mover os bits lidando com valores em hex (coisa de principiante rsrsr)

O algoritmo para isso é ir fazendo um XOR dos primeiros 16 bits com 0x8005 (no caso de um CRC-16) ?

O include crc16.h pode fazer isso?

Comment: Um link que pode ajudar: https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/CRC-Calculation-C-Code